# Regex Manupulation

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

My input is

```
String input = "I am doing <span id='icms'>test</span>on <span id='icms'>regex</span> exp."
```

Now My output is coming like

```
"regex exp"
```

But my output is needed like this

```
I am doing test on regex exp
```

So need help on the regex and matcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two replacements. First replace `<span[^>]*id=['"]icms['"][^>]*>([^<]*)</span>` by `' $1 '` (without the quotes; they just show you that you have to pre- and append a space) and then replace `' {2,}'` (without the quotes again) by a single space.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> "I am doing <span id='icms'>test</span>on <span id='icms'>regex</span> exp." -replace '<span[^>]*id=[''"]icms[''"][^>]*>([^<]*)</span>',' $1 ' -replace ' {2,}',' '
I am doing test on regex exp.
```

Comment: Why not replace `<[^>]+>` with just an empty string?

Comment: That would lead to »I am doing teston regex exp.«. Note the missing space between »test« and »on«.

Comment: can u please provide me the regex exp ,But I need to do it only for span tag whose id='icms'

Comment: Fixed. At the cost of a much more complex RE

Comment: How can i do it greedy way with <span id='icms'></span>

Answer (score 1):

The following sould capture every part that is not a tag, which seems to be what you want:

```
(?:(.*)<.*?>(.*))*
```

EDIT:

then for this specific tag :

`(?:(.*?)<span id='icms'>([^<]*?)</span>(.*))*`

Comment: Thanks for help. Actually I need this only for                  <span id='icms'></span> tag.

Comment: But not all the tag I want to only omit <span id='icms'><span> tag     where span id ='icms'